# (anti-)virus preventing my apps from working?

Tags: antivirus

On my other PC (windows XP SP2) i ran my app from my main pc using msvc05 to sort files across the network and found it couldnt move directories. One app i used on that PC couldnt function properly. All the files were automatically read only. Now on this PC i have the same symptom. Nothing act funny quiet yet (tortoiseSVN did but i am not sure readonly was the problem) but i know eventually it will. Why is everything read only? i googled the problem and it said turn off bitdefender. I havent DL bitdefender. I DL norton antivirus and gave my comp a scan, no virus came up. Whats going on?

NOTE: On this pc the read only box does not have a checkmark but a square. Going into the folder all files have a empty box. I turned on view invisible files and system files. I dont see anything in that folder. The other PC i think may have checkmarks but i am unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you (or your app_) has the rights to write in those directories?

If you only have read rights, it apears as if the files are readonly.

Comment: i wanted to move the dir they were in. i'm sure the dir was read only. its weird that i can move it in IE with no problem and didnt have any errors with firefox (with cache files and stuff). I dont use that pc often and its only used to archive so it isnt to much of a problem ATM